# How to get properties of the object subjected to event using Fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, events, fabricjs

Using Fabric.js 1.1.6, I have the following:

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect({});
rect.on('moving', function(obj) {
    // I want to retrieve and set properties from the
    // object rect from inside this event function
});
```

- Is it possible to retrieve and modify the `rect` properties from inside the function called by the event?
- If it is, how do I do that?
- If it is not, any suggestions on how could I modify rect properties from inside the event function?

Thank you in advance!

--

**Update:** The above question is correctly answered by @plalx, but I actually have this in a greater context:

```
function SomeClass()
{
    this.rect = new fabric.Rect({});
    this.rect.on('moving', function(obj) {
        // here, this.rect is undefined
    });
}
```

Well, in the latter context, I can't only use this.rect inside the function, because there `this` refers to the function, not to SomeClass.

How about now, what are the answers for the three questions above?

Comment: If a function refers to certain variables that are in scope when it is created, it will "close over" those variables. That means they will be available to it for access and modify even if they are not in scope when you invoke it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Is it possible to retrieve and modify the rect properties from inside
>   the function called by the event?"

Not only it is possible but it is very simple ;) You should read about [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) in JavaScript.

For question #1

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect({});
rect.on('moving', function(obj) {
    rect.someProperty = 'test';
});
```

For question #2

```
function SomeClass() {
    var rect = this.rect = new fabric.Rect({});

    this.rect.on('moving', function(obj) {
        // here, this.rect is undefined
        rect.someProperty;
    });
}
```

Comment: ok, this answers my question, but I actually have this thing in a greater context... see the edit, please

Comment: I am sorry, but I didn't think that what I mentioned in the update would matter... JavaScript is quite unusual for me (I'm in use with C# and C family).

Comment: @Girardi, Yes, I can understand why you find it troublesome, like I said read about closures in and OO JavaScript ;)

Comment: the #2 is a very clever approach, taking advantage of the almost always reference which are passed to the variables when doing `var obj1 = obj2`! Thank you!