# Bind events to object in fabricJS

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Using latest Fabric.js, I have the code:

```
var imageAdded = new Image();
imageAdded.onload = function (img) {
    var imgAdded = new fabric.Image(imageAdded, {
        clipName: picID,
        clipTo: function (ctx) {
            return _.bind(clipByName, imgAdded)(ctx)
        }
    });
    canvas.add(imgAdded);

    imgAdded.on("object:selected", function (e) { // It doesn't pass this function
        alert(e.target.clipName + " is selected");
        e.target.clipTo = null;
        canvas.renderAll();
    });
};
```

- I want to alert when I select an object but no alert is showed because the function where I made a comment in the code doesn't work.
- I tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15916603/how-to-get-properties-of-the-object-subjected-to-event-using-fabric-js) but still can't make it possible.

I appreciate every suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want an event for a specific object use:

```
imgAdded.on("selected", function(){alert(this.clipName);});
```

if want event for canvas and all objects:

```
canvas.on("object:selected", function(e){alert(e.target.clipName);});
```

Comment: Thank you for your code! That is definitely work. Anyway, I couldn't fill **selection:cleared** or **cleared** in this `imgAdded.on("selection:cleared", .....);`. How can I call this event when imgAdded is not selected. In addition, where can I learn more about advance Fabric Js ?

Comment: "selection:cleared" is a canvas event, not an object event. check also "before:selection:cleared" because there probably you have chance to get the selected object. http://fabricjs.com/docs/ here are docs.

Comment: This isn't working for object prototypes, specifically for when they are added to the canvas or created, ie `fabric.Object.prototype.on("added", function(){...})`